# Xcode: how to continue building after errors

Tags: xcode, xcode9

How can I make Xcode continue building after it has got some errors? I would like to see as many errors as I can to get a picture what to do next.

Comment: What you describe is the default behaviour for Xcode. Did you change a setting or something ?

Comment: @PaulR  Thats what has seemed to happen

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To the extent that this is possible, it will happen if the checkbox in the prefs is checked:

[image]

But some compile errors will eventually cause the compiler to give up, regardless.

Comment: It is in the General tab in the Preferences dialog.

Comment: @matt It would be great to have an example for what kind of errors the compiler will continue because when I have checked this option in my project I get the same behaviour and this makes me think that this option doesn't work

Comment: @BlazejSLEBODA Perhaps it takes a lot of errors for any difference to emerge? I really have no idea. Maybe it isn't applicable to the Swift compiler at all.

Comment: I wonder if there is a flag or something to toggle this with xcodebuild. Anyone?